# JQuery validation not running when submitted by a button from outside of IFrame

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using JQuery UI dialog to host a form that is inside of an IFrame. I am saving the form by calling...

```
$(myIframe).contents().find('form').submit()
```

...from the dialogs save button.

This will submit the form, but it doesn't seem to call the validation (I'm using JQuery unobtrusive validation). If I place a submit button inside the IFrame it works just fine, so I know the validation logic is correct.

How do I get the validation to run properly?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling the jquery submit function directly from the parent window, call a method inside of the IFrame that calls the submit method.

Parent window...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
            myFrame.submitForm();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Child window...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm() {
        $('form').submit();
    }
</script>
```