# Parent Submit Function Submitting iFrame Form Without Verifying Input Types

Tags: javascript, html

So I am using this code in my parent window's 'onclick' button attribute:

```
window.frames['sample'].document.forms['sample_sheet'].submit();
```

Originally (and via HTML's built in check) the iframe's submit button, when clicked, will give me a verification error if I type a letter in a number input field and try to submit it. For example:

```
 <input type="number" />
```

therefore if I type "RG" in that input, I will get "Please enter a number" when I try to submit.

But with the submit function I am using above for the parent window button, the form will submit no matter what, and I also have an HTML min='0' attribute that is being overlooked via the submit function (like even if I enter a negative number it will submit without an HTML check). I really need the HTML verificaiton to work prior to submit! Why is it not working now  and how can I make it verify?

[image]

HTML in Parent Window

```
 <iframe src="sample/"
            frameborder="" name="sample" id="sample" class="contentiframe"></iframe>

 <a onclick="window.frames['sample'].document.forms['sample_sheet'].submit();" data-transition="flip" data-theme="" data-icon="check">
                  Submit
```

FORM HTML WITHIN THE iFRAME

```
<form id="sample_sheet" name="sample_sheet" action="php/upload.php" method="post">
<table>         .......
<tr>
            <td>Sample Sequence</td>
            <td><input type="number" name="sample_no" id="sample_no" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
            <td>Waste Weight</td>
            <td><input type="number" step="any" min="0" name="waste_wt" id="waste_wt" /></td>
        </tr>
</table>
<!--<input type="submit" value="Submit" />-->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer here after installing the jquery validation plugin, which was all I was missing.

[Jquery Validate and send form with a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375901/jquery-validate-and-send-form-with-a-link)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using event.PreventDefault() within the callback function? This will stop any default actions on the button click.

Comment: I need a little bit more code than this to see what's going on. But that is a good place to start. Preventing default.

Comment: I have never implemented any PreventDefault functions

Comment: This is my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590303/jquery-validation-not-running-when-submitted-by-a-button-from-outside-of-iframe